# Rails/PostgreSQL - Query to update all dates adding 1 day

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to execute an update_all query to update a datetime column adding 1 day to the current value of this column on all rows.

I could achieve that using .each and .update, but it would be more efficient to perform in a single query.

Is it possible to achieve that using Rails and PostgreSQL?

Comment: This is trivial to express as a query.  It should be pretty basic in Ruby as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails way of updating all records

```
Model.update_all("column_name = (column_name + '1 DAY'::INTERVAL)")
```

This update query can be run via rails console.

Note: update_all method does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations and it will not change updated_at timestamp.

Answer (score 7):

```
UPDATE table SET date_field = date_field + 1;
```

Or ..

```
UPDATE table SET date_field = date_field + INTERVAL '1 DAY';
```

Comment: just wondering, as I wasn't aware of such use; at first the +1 (without any specification) looks quite random

Comment: I also found it out by accidentally running `SELECT CURRENT_DATE + 1 ;`  :-)