# invalid input syntax for type interval in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I execute following query, it returned errors

```
SELECT 
    type1,
    type2
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    date  >= '2021-05-22' - interval '22 day'
```

> Invalid operation: invalid input syntax for type interval: "2021-05-22"

I'd like to set like '2021-05-22' in hard coding style. Where is the wrong point of this ?

If someone has any insight, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You tag your question with postgre but your title says mysql. Please give us consitent informations

Answer (score 3):

Postgres is strongly typed. Sometimes it will typecast for you, but it won't guess based on the content of the text. When you give it `text - interval` it is trying to cast the text into an interval, not a date.

You need to cast the text to a date explicitly.

```
select '2020-05-22'::date - interval '22 day';
```

You could also simplify this.

```
select '2020-04-30'::date
```

Comment: It is actually `unknown`, not `text`, but your reasoning is right.

Answer (score 2):

if you're dealing with days, you don't need to use interval. Just adding or subtracting an integer is enough:

```
SELECT current_date, current_date + 22, current_date - 22;

 current_date |  ?column?  |  ?column?  
--------------+------------+------------
 2021-05-27   | 2021-06-18 | 2021-05-05
```

So, this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date  >= '2021-05-22'::date - 22;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c00665c3acd32b7f3d35e427436c4336)

Check this other [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49012122/2275388)